# How to handle duplicates in an UPDATE on a primary key in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, duplication

Let's assume a scenario with the entities `Person` and `Company` and a table `PersonCompanyStocks` that models how many stocks a persons owns of a certain company (N:M cardinality). For example:

```
person | company | num_stocks
-----------------------------
Alice  | foo     | 300
Bob    | foo     | 100
Bob    | bar     | 200
```

This table uses `(person, company)` as a primary key to guarantee unique entries, and foreign keys to the respective person/company table (I'm only using string IDs for simplicity).

Now let's assume company `bar` buys company `foo`. We want to update the table in a way that it becomes:

```
person | company | num_stocks
-----------------------------
Alice  | bar     | 300
Bob    | bar     | 300
```

Looking only at `Alice`'s record suggests to use a naive approach like:

```
UPDATE
  PersonCompanyStocks
SET
  company = "bar"
WHERE
  company = "foo"
```

However this update fails with `duplicate key value violates unique constraint ...` because for `Bob` there already is a row with the key `("Bob", "bar")`. For `INSERT`'s Postgres supports [`ON CONFLICT DO ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34639631/1804173), but it looks like there is no equivalent for `UPDATE`. And clearly we also have to deal with properly merging the `num_stock` value of the two rows.

What is the best strategy to approach this problem? I only see a relatively ugly solution:

- One query to determine the duplicates.
- One `UPDATE` to merge the duplicates into the final row.
- One `DELETE` to remove the offending duplicates.
- The above `UPDATE` to do the renaming in rows without duplicates.

This feels complex and is probably prone to race conditions. Does Postgres offer any trick to solve this more elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need move stocks between companies, right? What means we need add stocks to existing users and change company for new users. Or, what the same, we could delete all stocks of company "foo" and `insert .. on conflict` new rows for company "bar"

```
with rows as (                                             
  delete from PersonCompanyStocks 
    where company = 'foo'
    returning person, num_stocks
)
insert into PersonCompanyStocks (person, company, num_stocks) 
  select person, 'bar', num_stocks from rows
  on conflict(person,company) do update set 
    num_stocks = PersonCompanyStocks.num_stocks + excluded.num_stocks;
```

Transactional, no race conditions here thanks to row locking during delete.

Comment: This is very elegant, indeed. Nitpick: I had to insert an `SET` after the `DO UPDATE`. It is also worth noting that `excluded` is a built-in magic specifically for referring to the conflicting row as documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT). I've also found this pattern in the docs under [Data-Modifying Statements in WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).

Comment: oops, my error. I noticed another one and just updated query. Correct, `excluded` is special name for the conflicting row.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is good. To avoid race conditions, do it all in a single transaction and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` all the rows that you intend to modify (pessimistic locking).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Do you perhaps have a rough outline of how the first two steps actually look like in practice? Not having written any meaningful SQL in years, I'm struggling a bit, e.g. whether I can/should avoid loading all the offending IDs into the host programming language or whether I can do it all in SQL.

Comment: You run something like `SELECT * FROM personcompanystocks WHERE company IN ('foo', 'bar') FOR UPDATE;`. You need those rows anyway, so that's no wasted effort. It puts row lock on the selected rows, so that no concurrent transaction can modify them.